# Jinja for loop not looping the correct amount of times

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I've created a for loop in Jinja, which works alongside Flask but for some reason It's not looping the correct amount of times.

```
          {% if news %}
          {% set count = -1 %}
          {% for new in news[::-1] %}
          {% set count = count + 1 %}
          <div class="news" style="display:flex;align-items:center;">
            <img src="{{ postpfp[count] }}" style="width:50px;border-radius:50%;margin-right:10px;">
            <div style="display:block;">
              <p style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:-3px;font-size:18px;"><b>{{ new.update }}</b></p>
              <p style="font-size:13px;">By {{ new.postby }} | {{ new.postdate }} {{ new.posttime }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
          <p style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:-5px;">No Updates to Display</p>
          {% endif %}
```

As you can see, for each row in the news table there is it loops through that many times.
There are 2 rows in the table, yet it only loops through once.

Database Table:
[image]

In case you need it, here's my python code:

```
        news = News.query.all()
        if news:
            pfps = []
            for new in news[::-1]:
                urls = db.session.query(Users).filter_by(username=new.postby).first().pfpurl
                pfps.append(urls)
                
            return render_template('dashboard.html', 
                user=current_user.username,
                email=current_user.email,
                admin=current_user.isAdmin,
                plan=current_user.plan,
                date=current_user.joindate,
                pfp=current_user.pfpurl,
                news=news,
                users=db.session.query(Users).count(),
                postpfp=pfps)
```

Comment: how do you know that it loops only once?

Comment: I returned the value of `count` to the page, and it was 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask has a built-in loop counter:

```
{{ loop.index }} #counts  1,2,3...
{{ loop.index0 }} #counts 0,1,2,3...
```

So you can use:

```
<img src="{{ postpfp[loop.index0] }}"...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `count` variable is not worked as you might expect due to jinja scope behaviour. `count` is -1 at each iteration.

> Please keep in mind that it is not possible to set variables inside a
> block and have them show up outside of it. This also applies to loops.
> The only exception to that rule are if statements which do not
> introduce a scope.

[Reference](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#assignments)

Comment: As far as I know, the variable isn't showing up outside of the block.

Comment: and loops. how does then it show 2 rows when it does only 1 iteration?

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about, because in the python code I provided it iterates twice.